# copying files from iPod classic to clementine library

Tags: 12.04, sync, ipod, clementine

today i installed clementine on my PC with Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it. this application can recognize my iPod good, but there is a problem when i want to copy files to library; i don't have any option to do this.
in rhythmBox when i drag music category from device subcategory to library folder, everything done great.
 is there anyway to do it in clementine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reason I don't understantd (bug ?), the "Copy to library" menu option is greyed out when I click on a song in the subtree of my device.
However, once a song is added to the playlist, The "Copy to Library" is present and works.

So, in order to import all songs, here's the workaround I found :

- Add all the songs to the playlist (Click on the first, then hold shift and click on the last).
- Then, select all the songs in the playlist
- Then right-click on them and select "Copy to Library"
- Et voilà !